# Different point buffer length left and right in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, buffer

How am I supposed to split my buffer at different length from left and right. I need to make buffer 100m left and 300 m on right. Green is 100m while blue is 300m.

[image: Green is 100m while blue is 300m]

Comment: Where would you draw the split line for a combined buffer around multiple points like on the right side of your diagram?

Comment: at the center of the point. is it possible to do it? right now i just manually split the buffer one by one using "cut polygon tool"

Comment: So you would have five different very close lines for the points on the right? Because the spaces between them are far less than 100m, so you might need to think about which buffer takes priority in these areas. "Left" and "right" of a point is a pretty arbitrary concept. What is your end goal in splitting these buffers? Are you actually trying to split the buffers by a cardinal direction (i.e. on a north/south line), or by a linear feature like a road that that the points lie on? This kind of context might help people give you some better solutions.